# Is Silverstripe's Configuration API a Singleton?

Tags: php, silverstripe

According to the Documentation,

The Configuration API can be seen as separate from other forms of variables in the SilverStripe system due to three properties API:

```
Configuration is per class, not per instance.
Configuration is normally set once during initialization and then not changed.
Configuration is normally set by a knowledgeable technical user, such as a developer, not the end user.
```

Question is the configuration API a Singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like a Singleton, since most access to the Config API goes through `Config::inst()` which will always return the currently active `Config` instance. This instance will remain the same, until you decide to change it with `Config::set_instance($myNewConfigInstance)`.

So yes, there's a Singleton pattern implemented there, but you can still have multiple instances of `Config` (you can use this to isolate environments, like tests or whatever).

Here's an example of how you could switch Config during code-execution:

```
// preserve old config
$defaultConfig = Config::inst();
// create a new config
Config::set_instance(new Config());

// … do stuff that will use the new config

// switch back to the default config once you're done
Config::set_instance($defaultConfig);
```